# Android two way data binding with spinner not working

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding

I'm making a form in my app and I was trying to use two-way data binding to avoid the need of manually fill the object on the final button click. I was able to easily do it with an edit text and a string field, but I can't make it work with a spinner.

The Spinner is like this:

```
<Spinner
        android:id="@+id/species_spinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/simple_margin"
        android:selectedItemPosition="@={speciesConverter.toInt(animal.species)}"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3" />
```

The converter

```
class SpeciesConverter {
    @InverseMethod("toSpecies")
    fun toInt(species: Animal.Species) = species.ordinal

    fun toSpecies(index: Int) = Animal.Species.values()[index]
}
```

And the activity:

```
class AnimalRegisterActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    val binding: ActivityAnimalRegisterBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_animal_register)

    species_spinner.adapter = generateStringAdapter(Animal.Species.values()
            .map {
                it.getPrettyString(this)
            })

    val animal = Animal()
    binding.animal = animal
    binding.executePendingBindings()

    register_animal_button.setOnClickListener {
        Log.i("REGISTER ANIMAL", animal.toString())
    }
}

private fun generateStringAdapter(stringList: List<String>) =
        ArrayAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                stringList)
                .apply { setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item) }
```

}

The `Animal` `species` field is an `enum`.

Does anyone know what's wrong? Every information and example that I found are like that. I don't know what I'm missing.

Comment: If Species is an enum How can `Animal.Species.values()` give an List<String>?

Comment: With the `map` function: `map { it.getPrettyString(this) }`